# SonarQube binding does not work VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarqube

I am trying to link a local ASPNET Core application to SonarQube through the team explorer connection.

My ASPNET.Core project has been recently updated to the latest version of dotnet core and also has a `.csproj` file. I am developing in Visual Studio 2017 with the latest version of C#.

Whenever I try to bind to my SonarQube instance (v6.1) I am prompted to authentication which I provide. Once logged in an attempt to download the compatible projects fails with the error

[image]

I also get the following output in sonarLint window

[image]

Any ideas on how I can make SonarQube recognise this project so I can bind it?

Answer (score 0):

SonarLint Connected Mode is not yet available for .Net Core projects, you can track progress on [GitHub issue #151](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/issues/151) .